# Play wav sound file continuously in PsychoPy

Tags: audio, psychopy

I have a sound file which plays a beep and I want to play the sound continuously for a few seconds, so that it sounds like one continuous sound. Here is my code

```
alarm = sound.Sound('alarm.wav', secs = 5)
alarm.play()
```

But it only plays for 1 sec, which is how long the original sound is. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here're some solutions:

1. Use psychopy to generate the beep:

   ```py
   alarm = sound.Sound(700, secs=5)  # 700Hz beep
   ```
2. When you want a length that is a multiple of the original file, loop it, although this is likely to generate some clicks at each repeat (because of the sudden jump in amplitude, unless they match perfectly):

   ```py
   alarm = sound.Sound('alarm.wav', loops=5)
   ```
3. Use an audio editor to extend the beep to five seconds, making sure that there's no click at the loops. This is probably better than (2) if you have a fixed duration.
4. If you have multiple playback lengths, e.g. between conditions, use the `alarm.stop()` at the appropriate time during the experiment. Then either set `loops` to a high number or audio edit the sound to be long enough as in (3) so that you know that it only stops on your command.

Answer (score 1):

The duration parameter (secs) doesn't work like this. If `alarm.wav` was longer than 5 seconds, it would play only the first five seconds (i.e. I think it could truncate a file, although its primary purpose is for defining the duration of sounds specified as notes, rather than via an external sound file). But it isn't going to automatically pad out that period by repeatedly playing a file which has a smaller duration.

You should either use some sound editing software to concatenate five instances of `alarm.wav` into another file, (the easiest solution) or create a loop to play it five times (which might be tricky to integrate into your drawing loop without slight timing glitches).